# Printing all subsets with only a given length in python

Tags: python, recursion

I have the task to print all subsets of given length, I have created the functions to print out the all the subsets. Everything works fine the subsets are generated, but the output is wrong for each call. For example if I call print(get_subsets([1,2,3],2)) the output is [1,2] [1,3] [2,3] and [3]. Of course 3 is not supposed to be there and I can't figure out why. Any help will be appreciated and feedback of course.

```
def get_subsets(nums, k):
  all_subsets = []

  _gen_subsets(nums =nums,curr_idx =0,curr_subset=[],
               all_subsets=all_subsets)


  for curr_subset in all_subsets:
    if len(curr_subset) > k or len(curr_subset) < k:
      all_subsets.remove(curr_subset)


  return all_subsets


def _gen_subsets(nums,curr_idx, curr_subset, all_subsets):
  if curr_idx >= len(nums):
    all_subsets.append(curr_subset)
  else:
    itr_subset = curr_subset.copy()
    itr_subset.append(nums[curr_idx])

    _gen_subsets(nums=nums,
             curr_idx=curr_idx+1,
             curr_subset=itr_subset,
             all_subsets=all_subsets)

    _gen_subsets(nums=nums,
             curr_idx=curr_idx+1,
             curr_subset=curr_subset,
             all_subsets=all_subsets)
```

Comment: change `f len(curr_subset) > k or len(curr_subset) < k:` to `if len(curr_subset)!=k` as you are using or operation, this conditon only faill when length ==k ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate through a list from which you are also removing elements. This messed up the position and index of the list of subsets and gave you the wrong output.

Change the function get_subsets to this:

```
def get_subsets(nums, k):
    all_subsets = []

    _gen_subsets(nums =nums,curr_idx =0,curr_subset=[],
           all_subsets=all_subsets)

    final_subset = all_subsets.copy()
    for n in all_subsets:
        if len(n) != k:
            final_subset.remove(n)

    return final_subset
```

Or this:

```
def get_subsets(nums, k):
    all_subsets = []

    _gen_subsets(nums =nums,curr_idx =0,curr_subset=[],
           all_subsets=all_subsets)

    all_subsets = [n for n in all_subsets if len(n) == k]

    return all_subsets
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by this:

```py
  for curr_subset in all_subsets:
    if len(curr_subset) > k or len(curr_subset) < k:
      all_subsets.remove(curr_subset)
```

You are removing array elements while iterating. That leads to the following scenario: Initially you have array `[X1, X2, X3]`.
In the first iteration, you remove the first element `X1`. Then the second element `X2` becomes the first element and therefore, on the second iteration, the third element X3 (which has become the second element) is traversed and `X2` is skipped. That is why `[3]` is not removed from your array.

To solve this, you can change `get_subsets` function as below:

```py
def get_subsets(nums, k):
    all_subsets = []

    _gen_subsets(nums =nums,curr_idx =0,curr_subset=[],
           all_subsets=all_subsets)

    all_subsets = [subset for subset in all_subsets if len(subset) == k]

    return all_subsets
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe thes two will help you?

```
def Combinations(l, d):
    if (d <= 1) or (len(l) <= 1):
        return [[i] for i in l]
    else:
        result = []
        for i in range(len(l)):
            c = l[i]
            lx = l[:i]+l[i+1:]

            for cmb in Combinations(lx, d-1):
                result.append([c]+cmb)
        return result
print(*Combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2), sep='\n')


def Allocations(l, d):
    if (d <= 1) or (len(l) <= 1):
        return [[i] for i in l]
    else:
        result = []
        for i in range(len(l)+1-d):
            c = l[i]
            lx = l[i+1:]

            for cmb in Allocations(lx, d-1):
                result.append([c]+cmb)
        return result
print(*Allocations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3), sep='\n')
```